# What is the matrix with respect to given basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

My attempt:

```
         T(E1) = 2E1 + 3E1

         T(E2) = 2E2 + 3E3

         T(E3) = 2E3 + 3E2

         T(E4) = 2E4 + 3E4
```

I don't know how to write the matrix with respect to the given basis. If anybody help me I would be thankful.

Comment: Look up the definition of the matrix of a linear operator with respect to a given basis.

Comment: Also please use proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As you use the cannonical base you can just write the linear combination you get for each basis vector in each column of the matrix:

$$T(X) = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & & & \\ & 2 & 3 & \\  & 3 & 2 & \\ & & & 5 \end{bmatrix} X$$

Comment: 2 3                                                                                                                              3 2       im not getting this...how it comes @flawr

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: 2 3 in 2nd row and 3 2 in 3rd row i didn"t understand  how it comes@flawr

Answer (score 0):

Find the matrix one column at a time.  For instance, we find the second column by computing
$$
T(E_2) = 0E_1 + 2E_2 + 3E_3 + 0E_4
$$
So, our matrix has the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{?&0&?&?\\
?&2&?&?\\
?&3&?&?\\?&0&?&?}
$$